# Задаваемое количество создаваемых потоков

Tags: c++, многопоточность

Задание:
На вход получаю число N - количество потоков.
В ходе выполнения программы должно быть не более N потоков.

Проблема:
Если сделать функцию, которая будет создавать поток, а потом вызывать эту функцию N раз, то возникает проблема с функциями thread.join() и thread.detach(). Если сделать detach(), то, при завершении основного потока, остальные пропадут. Использование join() в этой функции убивает многопоточность.

Как можно задать N потоков, чтобы не было проблем с торможением или пропажей потоков? При этом чтобы одновременно работало не более N потоков.

Comment: Ну та не надо делать `join` в том цикле, который создает потоки. Делать `join` для всех потоком надо *потом*, когда все потоки уже созданы.

Comment: @AnT join вне функции сделать не могу, ибо поток существует лишь в функции, а вне его переменная не определена. Либо я чего-то ещё не знаю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот элементарная программа, которая создает `N` потоков (в дополнение к основному)

```
std::vector<std::thread> threads(N);
for (unsigned i = 0; i < N; ++i)
  threads[i] = std::thread(/* ваши параметры для i-го потока */);
...
for (unsigned i = 0; i < N; ++i)
  threads[i].join();
```

Все тривиально. Вам это чем-то не подходит?

---

Если вам нужно создавать поток в функции, то создавайте его в функции. Разумеется, при этом его придется из функции *возвращать*

```
std::thread my_create_thread_function(unsigned i)
{
  return std::thread(/* ваши параметры для i-го потока */);
}
```

а дальше снова

```
std::vector<std::thread> threads(N);
for (unsigned i = 0; i < N; ++i)
  threads[i] = my_create_thread_function(i);
...
for (unsigned i = 0; i < N; ++i)
  threads[i].join();
```